# How to create merge sort array using calloc in C language?

Tags: arrays, c, linux, terminal, mergesort

I am new to programming and I am stuck on this. I have to edit a file to be able to sort an array. Previously, it was programmed to sort arrays that are powers of two. Now I have to make a change for it to be able to sort arrays of any number. I Could have sworn this worked when I submitted it, but my professor came back and said it doesn't work ‍♀️

I have to use `calloc`. The other files don't need to be changed. The only change I need to make is in the **mergesort.c** file and the **main.c** file that houses the array. I absolutely cannot change the other files so I'm not going to include them but they are correct as I have copied them directly from my text book and have ran them previously for arrays of power 2.

I also previously tried creating an altkey and assigning it the key but he said not to do that..

##### This is the code in **main.c**:

```c
#include "mergesort.h"

int main(void) {
    int key[] = { 4, 3, 1, 67, 55, 8, 0, 4, -5, 37, 7, 4, 2, 9, 1 };
    int sz = sizeof(key) / sizeof(int); /* the size of key[]    */

    printf("Before mergesort:\n");
    wrt(key, sz);

    mergesort(key, sz);

    printf("After mergesort:\n");
    wrt(key, sz);
}
```

##### This is the current code in **mergesort.c**:

```c
#include "mergesort.h"

void mergesort(int key[], int n) {
    int j, k, m, *w, i;

    w = calloc(n, sizeof(int)); /* allocate workspace   */
    assert(w != NULL);          /* check that calloc() worked */

    for (k = 1; k < n; k *= 2) {
        for (j = 0; j < n - k; j += 2 * k)
            merge(key + j, key + j + k, w + j, k, k);
        for (j = 0; j < n; ++j)
            key[j] = w[j]; /* 11/12/22 write w back into key */
    }

    free(w); /* free the workspace */
}
```

##### Merge Function in **merge.c** (I can't edit this file)

```
#include "mergesort.h"

void merge(int a[], int b[], int c[], int m, int n) {
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

    while (i < m && j < n)
        if (a[i] < b[j])
            c[k++] = a[i++];
        else
            c[k++] = b[j++];
    while (i < m)                   /* pick up any remainder */
        c[k++] = a[i++];
    while (j < n)
        c[k++] = b[j++];
}
```

##### Output:

```
Before mergesort:
4    3    1   67   55    8    0    4   -5   37    7    4    2   9    1
After mergesort:
-5    0    0    1    2    3    4    4    4    7    8    9   15   15   55
```

Comment: Please reformat your code. It is not easy to understand.

Comment: @MayukhSarkar again - I'm new to this. What part? Should I take out the comments?

Comment: A lot of lines are indented too much and headers are not formatted. Also same function is split in chunks.

Comment: @MayukhSarkar ok I think I fixed it. Let me know if it's still hard to read :)

Comment: `key = calloc(n, sizeof(int));` changes the pointer for `key` to point to a new array. How do you expect to ever read the original input array?

Comment: omg thanks @BillLynch! that was in there from when I was trying to assign altkey. Took it out and it sorts now, but it's assigning 0 so some of the numbers.
  -5   0   0   0   1   2   0   4   0   0   7   0  55   0   0

Comment: `assert` is meant for debugging conditions which you believe to be true always; it is really not appropriate at all for checking if the allocation failed.

Comment: Thanks @Neil although not quite sure that's where my issue is. I'm playing around with `merge` function and that seems to give me different outputs... Just not sure how to reflect that k isn't always going to the correct size..

Comment: I agree, it is unlikely to be your issue! :] Where is `merge` located? Why `calloc`?

Comment: @neil I'll add it above. Calloc because that's what my professor required us to use :'( I can't edit the merge.c file. I can only edit mergesort.c

Comment: Are you sure `merge` is picking up the right values? Why don't you print `a`, `b`, and after `c`, just to be sure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To adapt your bottom-up iterative `mergesort` function for non powers of 2 lengths, you will need to special case the last pair of slices at each iteration of the outer loop: stop the inner loop whenever there is fewer elements than 2 full slices and merge the last pair of slices if its right half is not empty.

Here is a modified version of your code:

```
void mergesort(int key[], int n) {
    int i, j, k;
    int *w = calloc(n, sizeof(*w));  /* allocate workspace   */
    assert(w != NULL);          /* check that calloc() worked */

    for (k = 1; k < n; k *= 2) {
        /* merge all the full pairs */
        for (j = 0; j + 2 * k < n; j += 2 * k) {
            merge(key + j, key + j + k, w + j, k, k);
        }
        if (j + k < n) {
            /* merge the last pair if right half is not empty */
            merge(key + j, key + j + k, w + j, k, n - (j + k));
            j = n;
        }
        /* write merged pairs in w back into key */
        for (i = 0; i < j; i++) {
            key[i] = w[i];
        }
    }
    free(w); /* free the workspace */
}
```

Note also these remarks:

- the above code does not achieve an optimal balance of pair lengths:  the merge is still performed on slices whose left part's length is a power of 2.
- the `merge` function (which you cannot modify) should declare `a` and `b` as `const int *` and use a test `if (a[i] <= b[j])` for better performance on arrays with many duplicates.
- the type `size_t` should be used for the length and index variables.
- the write back loop could be omitted in all but the last phase for better performance, using 2 working pointers.

Here is an improved version:

```
void mergesort(int key[], int n) {
    int i, j, k;
    int *w = calloc(n, sizeof(*w));  /* allocate workspace   */
    assert(w != NULL);          /* check that calloc() worked */

    int *w1 = key;
    int *w2 = w;
    int *w3;

    for (k = 1; k < n; k *= 2) {
        /* merge all the full pairs */
        for (j = 0; j + 2 * k < n; j += 2 * k) {
            merge(w1 + j, w1 + j + k, w2 + j, k, k);
        }
        if (j + k < n) {
            /* merge the last pair if right half is not empty */
            merge(w1 + j, w1 + j + k, w2 + j, k, n - (j + k));
        } else {
            /* copy the left slice of the last pair */
            for (i = j; i < n; i++) {
                w2[i] = w1[i];
        }
        /* swap the working pointers */
        w3 = w2;
        w2 = w1;
        w1 = w3;
    }
    /* write w back to key if needed */
    if (w1 == w) {
        for (i = 0; i < j; i++) {
            key[i] = w[i];
        }
    }
    free(w); /* free the workspace */
}
```

Comment: You're a lifesaver!! This worked! Sucks I can't edit the merge file because that would solve a lot of my problems. Thank you so much!! Going to review to make sure I understand what you did here, but this seems to work for now! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason your prof says things don't work as intended is your merge function.

You call `merge(key + j, key + j + k, w + j, k, k);`. Here you assume that the two arrays you are merging contain `k` elements. This is not the case, with 15 elements in the array when `k=2` and `j=12` you need two merge two sorted arrays of length 2 and 1 respectively. Therefore your code is prone to an overflow.

Therefore your call should be:
`merge(key + j, key + j + k, w + j, k, k-((n-j)/2))`
Now this may depend on your compiler but the division should floor down to 1 instead of 1.5.

Another note I'd like to make:

Code doesn't exist in a vacuum. People will use, and more importantly read your code.

Although your code makes sense, do make an effort to keep it readable. Lines such as: `c[k++] = a[i++];` make use of hyper specific nuances around C that probably don't translate well to other platforms. Although the code is technically correct, other programmers will have a harder time to decrypt your syntax and interpret the logic of your program. If you added the additions as part of the write for performance reason, know that the compiler is far better than you are at making efficient code. Leave efficiency to the compiler, most people who write "efficient code" write unreadable code that the compiler writes better anyways.

<strike>This may seem trivial for such a program of less than 100 lines of code, but in the future you will definitely be turning in assignments with 300+ lines of code. On top of that the inner-workings of this program will be so much more complicated and vast that your TA/Professor will give up and give you a bad grade.</strike>

Edit: sorry for the long text but tldr: write code to learn and communicate easily.

Overall I like your solution though and I didn't find any other errors. Hope your class is going well :).

Comment: Thanks so much for your feedback. I see where you were going and I for sure know my issue is in merge. I tried your solution and that didn't seem to work either. The output was `-5   4   0   1   0  55   0   0   0   0   0   7   0   2   0`. 

As for the c[k++] etc I got that right out of a textbook. It was code given to me so I had no say on how to write it and a requirement of the assignment is not to change it. I do see and understand what you mean though so I'll keep that in mind. I still have a lot to learn - thanks for the tips!!